How to fix database update PendingModelChangesWarning error
I am trying to create seeding data. When I run "dotnet ef database update" I get the following error :
Build started...

Build succeeded.

System.InvalidOperationException: An error was generated for warning
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.PendingModelChangesWarning':
The model for context 'RepositoryContext' has pending changes. Add a
new migration before updating the database. This exception can be
suppressed or logged by passing event ID
'RelationalEventId.PendingModelChangesWarning' to the
'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
'AddDbContext'.

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.EventDefinition`1.Log[TLoggerCategory](IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, TParam arg)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggerExtensions.PendingModelChangesWarning(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, Type contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)


An error was generated for warning
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.PendingModelChangesWarning':
The model for context 'RepositoryContext' has pending changes. Add a
new migration before updating the database. This exception can be
suppressed or logged by passing event ID
'RelationalEventId.PendingModelChangesWarning' to the
'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
'AddDbContext'.

My RepositoryContext.cs is :
using Entities.Models;
using Entities.Models.Enums;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Repositories
{
    public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<AgeGroup> AgeGroups { get; set; }
        
        public DbSet<Hairdresser> Hairdressers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HairdressingService> HairdressingServices { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CustomerAppointment> CustomerAppointments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HairdressingServiceLocalization> HairdressingServiceLocalizations { get; set; }

        public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<HairdressingService>().HasMany(x => x.AgeGroups)
                                                        .WithMany(y => y.HairdressingService)
                                                        .UsingEntity("HairdressingServiceAgeGroups");

            modelBuilder.Entity<HairdressingServiceLocalization>().HasOne(l => l.HairdressingService)
                                                                    .WithMany(h => h.Localizations)
                                                                    .HasForeignKey(l => l.HairdressingServiceId)
                                                                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Hairdresser>().HasMany(x => x.HairdressingServices)
                                                .WithMany(y => y.Hairdresser)
                                                .UsingEntity("HairdresserHairdressingServices");


            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAppointment>().HasMany(c => c.HairdressingServices)
                                                        .WithMany(h => h.CustomerAppointment)
                                                        .UsingEntity("CustomerAppointmentHairdressingServices");

            SeedingData(modelBuilder);
        }

        private void SeedingData(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var ageGroup1 = new AgeGroup { Id = 1, MinAge = 0, MaxAge = 17 };
            var ageGroup2 = new AgeGroup { Id = 2, MinAge = 18, MaxAge = 75 };
            var ageGroup3 = new AgeGroup { Id = 3, MinAge = 76, MaxAge = 125 };
            var ageGroup = new List<AgeGroup>();
            ageGroup.Add(ageGroup1);
            ageGroup.Add(ageGroup2);

            var hairdressingService1 = new HairdressingService { Id = 1, Name = "HairCut", Genders = { Gender.m }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0), Price = 100, Status = true };
            var hairdressingService2 = new HairdressingService { Id = 2, Name = "RazorShave", Genders = { Gender.m }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 40, 0), Price = 200, Status = true };
            var hairdressingService3 = new HairdressingService { Id = 3, Name = "HairColoring", Genders = { Gender.m }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0), Price = 300, Status = true };
            var hairdressingService4 = new HairdressingService { Id = 4, Name = "BrowShaping", Genders = { Gender.m, Gender.f }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 80, 0), Price = 400, Status = true };
            var hairdressingService5 = new HairdressingService { Id = 5, Name = "BeardGrooming", Genders = { Gender.m, Gender.f }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 100, 0), Price = 500, Status = true };
            var hairdressingService6 = new HairdressingService { Id = 6, Name = "ChildShave", Genders = { Gender.m, Gender.f }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 120, 0), Price = 600, Status = true };
            var hairdressingService7 = new HairdressingService { Id = 7, Name = "PermHair", Genders = { Gender.m, Gender.f }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 140, 0), Price = 700, Status = false };
            var hairdressingService8 = new HairdressingService { Id = 8, Name = "Manicure", Genders = { Gender.m, Gender.f }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 150, 0), Price = 800, Status = false };
            var hairdressingService9 = new HairdressingService { Id = 9, Name = "Pedicure", Genders = { Gender.m, Gender.f }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 160, 0), Price = 900, Status = false };
            var hairdressingService10 = new HairdressingService { Id = 10, Name = "GroomsCut", Genders = { Gender.m }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 180, 0), Price = 1000, Status = true };
            var hairdressingService11 = new HairdressingService { Id = 11, Name = "Makeup(Bride)", Genders = { Gender.f }, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 200, 0), Price = 1100, Status = false };

            List<HairdressingService> hairdressingServices = new List<HairdressingService>();
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService1);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService2);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService3);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService4);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService5);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService6);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService7);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService8);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService9);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService10);
            hairdressingServices.Add(hairdressingService11);

            var hairdresser1 = new Hairdresser { Id = 1, IdentityUserId = "1", Name = "Aydın", Surname = "Sevim", CanTakeClients = true };
            var hairdresser2 = new Hairdresser { Id = 2, IdentityUserId = "2", Name = "Alpay", Surname = "Aydıngüler", CanTakeClients = true };
            var hairdresser3 = new Hairdresser { Id = 3, IdentityUserId = "2", Name = "Deniz", Surname = "Dağ", CanTakeClients = false };
            var hairdressers = new List<Hairdresser>();
            hairdressers.Add(hairdresser1);
            hairdressers.Add(hairdresser2);
            hairdressers.Add(hairdresser3);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AgeGroup>().HasData(ageGroup1, ageGroup2, ageGroup3);
            modelBuilder.Entity<HairdressingService>().HasData(hairdressingServices);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Hairdresser>().HasData(hairdressers);
            modelBuilder.Entity("HairdressingServiceAgeGroups").HasData(
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 1, AgeGroupsId = 1 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 2, AgeGroupsId = 2 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 3, AgeGroupsId = 1 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 3, AgeGroupsId = 2 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 4, AgeGroupsId = 1 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 5, AgeGroupsId = 1 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 5, AgeGroupsId = 2 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 6, AgeGroupsId = 1 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 7, AgeGroupsId = 2 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 8, AgeGroupsId = 2 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 9, AgeGroupsId = 2 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 10, AgeGroupsId = 2 },
                new { HairdressingServiceId = 11, AgeGroupsId = 2 }
            );

            modelBuilder.Entity<HairdressingServiceLocalization>().HasData(// HairCut
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 1, HairdressingServiceId = 1, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Hair Cut" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 2, HairdressingServiceId = 1, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Saç Kesimi" },
                // RazorShave
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 3, HairdressingServiceId = 2, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Razor Shave" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 4, HairdressingServiceId = 2, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Jilet Traşı" },
                // HairColoring
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 5, HairdressingServiceId = 3, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Hair Coloring" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 6, HairdressingServiceId = 3, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Saç Boyama" },
                // BrowShaping
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 7, HairdressingServiceId = 4, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Brow Shaping" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 8, HairdressingServiceId = 4, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Kaş Şekillendirme" },
                // BeardGrooming
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 9, HairdressingServiceId = 5, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Beard Grooming" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 10, HairdressingServiceId = 5, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Sakal Bakımı" },
                // ChildShave
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 11, HairdressingServiceId = 6, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Child Shave" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 12, HairdressingServiceId = 6, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Çocuk Tıraşı" },
                // PermHair
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 13, HairdressingServiceId = 7, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Perm Hair" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 14, HairdressingServiceId = 7, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Perma Saç" },
                // Manicure
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 15, HairdressingServiceId = 8, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Manicure" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 16, HairdressingServiceId = 8, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Manikür" },
                // Pedicure
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 17, HairdressingServiceId = 9, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Pedicure" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 18, HairdressingServiceId = 9, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Pedikür" },
                // GroomsCut
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 19, HairdressingServiceId = 10, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Groom's Cut" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 20, HairdressingServiceId = 10, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Damat Kesimi" },
                // Makeup(Bride)
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 21, HairdressingServiceId = 11, Language = "en-GB", Name = "Makeup (Bride)" },
                new HairdressingServiceLocalization { Id = 22, HairdressingServiceId = 11, Language = "tr-TR", Name = "Makyaj (Gelin)" });



            modelBuilder.Entity("HairdresserHairdressingServices").HasData(
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 1 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 2 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 3 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 4 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 5 },
                new { HairdresserId = 2, HairdressingServicesId = 2 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 6 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 7 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 8 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 9 },
                new { HairdresserId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 10 }
            );

            CustomerAppointmentSeedingData(modelBuilder, hairdressingServices, hairdressers, ageGroup);

        }

        private void CustomerAppointmentSeedingData(ModelBuilder modelBuilder,
                                                List<HairdressingService> hairdressingServicesList,
                                                List<Hairdresser> hairdressersList,
                                                List<AgeGroup> ageGroups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Seeding CustomerAppointments...");
            var random = new Random();
            var customerAppointmentHairdressingServices = new List<object>();
            var customerAppointments = new List<CustomerAppointment>();
            var statuses = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CustomerAppointmentStatus)).Cast<CustomerAppointmentStatus>().ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                // Select a random Hairdresser, AgeGroup, and Status
                var hairdresser = hairdressersList[random.Next(hairdressersList.Count)];
                var ageGroup = ageGroups[random.Next(ageGroups.Count)];
                var status = statuses[random.Next(statuses.Length)];
                
                // Select 1 to 3 random HairdressingServices
                var selectedServices = hairdressingServicesList.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).Take(random.Next(1, 4)).ToList();
                
                // Calculate the total duration by summing the durations of selected services
                TimeSpan totalDuration = selectedServices.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, service) => sum.Add(service.Duration));

                // Random DateTime within the next 30 days
                DateTime appointmentDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(random.Next(1, 31)).AddHours(random.Next(9, 18)).AddMinutes(random.Next(0, 60));

                // Create the CustomerAppointment entity
                var customerAppointment = new CustomerAppointment
                {
                    Id = i + 1,
                    Name = $"Name{i + 1}",
                    Surname = $"Surname{i + 1}",
                    Gender = (Gender)random.Next(0, 2), // Random gender (0 or 1)
                    AgeGroupId = ageGroup.Id,
                    HairdresserId = hairdresser.Id,
                    Duration = totalDuration,
                    Price = selectedServices.Sum(service => service.Price),
                    DateTime = appointmentDateTime,
                    PhoneNumber = $"+90 123 456 78{random.Next(10, 99)}",
                    EMail = $"customer{i + 1}@example.com",
                    CreatedBy = null, // Replace with actual IdentityUser if needed
                    Status = status
                    /*
                    Id = i + 1,
                    Name = $"Name",
                    Surname = $"Surname",
                    Gender = Gender.m, // Random gender (0 or 1)
                    AgeGroupId = 1,
                    HairdresserId = 1,
                    Duration = new TimeSpan(0,20,0),
                    Price = selectedServices.Sum(service => service.Price),
                    DateTime = new DateTime(new DateOnly(2025,1,1), new TimeOnly(13,30)),
                    PhoneNumber = $"+90 123 456 78 22",
                    EMail = $"customer@example.com",
                    CreatedBy = null, // Replace with actual IdentityUser if needed
                    Status = CustomerAppointmentStatus.AwaitingApproval
                    */
                };

                customerAppointments.Add(customerAppointment);

                // Seed the many-to-many relationship (CustomerAppointment <-> HairdressingService)
                foreach (var service in selectedServices)
                {
                    customerAppointmentHairdressingServices.Add(
                        new { CustomerAppointmentId = customerAppointment.Id, HairdressingServicesId = service.Id }
                    );
                }

            }

            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAppointment>().HasData(customerAppointments);
            modelBuilder.Entity("CustomerAppointmentHairdressingServices").HasData(new { CustomerAppointmentId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 1 },
                new { CustomerAppointmentId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 2 },
                new { CustomerAppointmentId = 1, HairdressingServicesId = 4 });
            //modelBuilder.Entity("CustomerAppointmentHairdressingServices").HasData(customerAppointmentHairdressingServices);


        }
    }
}

When I type everything by hand like this it works :
    Id = i + 1,
    Name = $"Name",
    Surname = $"Surname",
    Gender = Gender.m, // Random gender (0 or 1)
    AgeGroupId = 1,
    HairdresserId = 1,
    Duration = new TimeSpan(0,20,0),
    Price = 100, //selectedServices.Sum(service => service.Price),
    DateTime = new DateTime(new DateOnly(2025,1,1), new TimeOnly(13,30)),
    PhoneNumber = $"+90 123 456 78 22",
    EMail = $"customer@example.com",
    CreatedBy = null, // Replace with actual IdentityUser if needed
    Status = CustomerAppointmentStatus.AwaitingApproval

But if I change even only the Price back to
    Price = selectedServices.Sum(service => service.Price),

It gives the same error. What am I missing here?

The error message says "The model for context 'RepositoryContext' has pending changes. Add a new migration before updating the database." Check the documentation about migrations

You cannot use random values for seeding data because EF Core compares two models to generate migrations, and random data will always result in differences. So forgot about Random, Guid.NewGuid, DateTime.Now, etc. Seeded data should be constant.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Can you type this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer please?

EF Core generates migrations by comparing two models:

The current model (your application's current state).
The model from the last migration.

If you're using random values or dynamic values like Guid.NewGuid() or DateTime.Now for seeding data, the model changes every time you run the application. As a result, EF Core detects a difference and generates a new migration each time.
This is why you're seeing the PendingModelChangesWarning. It's a warning that indicates the model has changed and you need to generate a new migration. However, in your case, this creates an infinite loop of migrations.
To resolve this issue, always use constant values when seeding data. This ensures the model remains consistent, preventing unnecessary migrations.
